# How to call specific outputs of the function as once

Tags: r

Suppose I have a function which returns me a list of output. How could I call a specific output at once? My original function is difficult and must return my output as a list. Sometimes I need to look at a special output (3 or 5 of them (out of 10). How can I do that very quickly using a shortcut code instead of repeating it several times to get one output each time?

For example,

```
x <- rnorm(1:5)
y <- rnorm(1:5)
myfun <- function(x,y){
    mult <- sumf <- distfu <- list()
    for(i in 1:5){
        mult[[i]] <- x[[i]]*y[[i]]
        sumf[[i]] <- x[[i]]+y[[i]]
        distfu[[i]] <- x[[i]]-y[[i]]
    }
    out <- list()
    out$mult <- mult
    out$sumf <- sumf
    out$distf <- distfu
    return(out)
}
myres <- myfun(x,y)
```

How can I call `myres$mult`and 
`myres$distf` only at one time?

I tried this: `myres$[c(1,3)]` but it was wrong.

**Please note that this example is simple, however, my function returns more than `10` outputs. So, if I need to only look at 5 of them, then I need to repeat this `myfun$..` five times. I just would like to know if there is a way to call all the `5` outputs at once`**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call a specific elements of a list you must do it like this:

```
myres[c(1,3)]
```

In your code there was a typo `$` after `myres`

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you, it was not a typo, I just thought it is the correct way to do it.